# Library to convert text into the C/C++ string

Tags: c++, c, converters

Is there an open source library to convert text into the C/C++ string for source code.
For example:

```
SELECT
  a
FROM T
```

should be converted

```
"SELECT\n"
"  a\n"
"FROM T\n"
```

I've found online [service](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/cpp_text_escape.php?lang=en) that can do such thing. But maybe exists open source solution on C/C++?

Comment: sed -e "s/^.*$/\"&\\\\n\"/"

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with `C++11`:

```
auto text = R"~(
SELECT
  a
FROM T
)~";
```